# increase image width base on likes and show the current Prozent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanna increase the image width base one likes amount. A user can get likes between 0 and 1000000.
From 0 to 1000 likes the blue image should show up. 
From 1001 to 10000 likes the green image should show up.
From 100001 to 750000 likes the image should show up.
From 750001 to 1000000 likes the yellow image should show up.
The current Prozent amount should show up as well at he bottom.

[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnNV.png)

May calculations seems to be wrong. If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

I have create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lotuz/eywraw8t/440884/)

```
  if(likes <= 1000){
    calc = ((likes/40) / 1000000) * 1000000;

    this.width = 180-likes


} else if (likes <= 10000){
     calc = ((likes/200) / 1000000) * 1000000;


} else if( likes <= 750000 ){
     calc = ((likes/10000) / 1000000) * 1000000;


} else if(likes <= 999999){
     calc = ((likes/10000) / 1000000) * 1000000;

}else if(likes > 1000000){
     calc = 100;
}
```

Comment: where is that jsfiddle?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it's now available

Comment: what went wrong with the current code ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim if type in the input 10001 get back 1% and the image should be small at the start and increase when i get more likes.

Comment: could explain more your use case when assigning width?

Comment: Sure. The more likes someone get's the bigger image becomes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnNV.png

Comment: i note that in your calculations you're reversing the logic, it's ?

Comment: Yes that's true but was not able to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    likes:0,
    width:0,
    initialWidth: 0,
    step: 0.025,
    imageUrls: ['https://i.postimg.cc/gn2d9BpV/blue.png', 'https://i.postimg.cc/3kyTN4dW/green.png', 'https://i.postimg.cc/0bXv9d5L/purple.png', 'https://i.postimg.cc/TKZXDdD0/yellow.png'],
    currentImageIndex: 0,
    smallestWidth: 7.5
  },
  methods: {
   getCurrentIndex() {
     if (!this.likes || this.likes <= 1000) {
       this.step = (25-this.smallestWidth)/1000;
        this.initialWidth = this.smallestWidth;
       return 0;
      }
     
      
    if (this.likes <= 10000) {
      this.step = 25/10000;
        this.initialWidth = 25;
       return 1;
      }
      
  if (this.likes < 1000000) {
        this.step = 25/999999;
        this.initialWidth = 50;
       return 2;
      }
      
      this.step = 0;
      this.initialWidth = 100;
      return 3;
    },
   prozent(){
  let likes = this.likes;
    
  this.currentImageIndex = this.getCurrentIndex();
  this.width = this.initialWidth + likes*this.step;
  
   if (this.likes == 0) {
     return 0;
    }
    
    return this.width.toFixed(2);
  }             
 },

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  likes
  <input v-model="likes" type="text"> 
  <br>
 <br>
 <div style="text-align:center">
 
  <img :src="imageUrls[currentImageIndex]" :style="{width: width + '%'}" >  
  
  <br>
  <br>
 
  {{ likes == 0 ? 0 : width }} %
  <br>
  
    {{ prozent() }}
    </div>
  <br><br>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, forget what I said. I jumped in before you posted the fiddle.

your image width should be determined like this:

```
:style=`width:${width}px`
```